# Filter 2D-array rows by a 1D-array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter, numpy-ndarray

I have a result of a database query as an nd-array. I'd like to filter the result by a list of IDs in the first column of the result.

```
Query result:    Filter:     Desired outcome:
ID | Field       ID          ID | Field
---+------       ---         ---+------
0  | Asd         1           1  | Wat
1  | Wat         2           2  | Cat
2  | Cat
6  | Yep
```

Of course list comprehensions could be used:

```
out = [i for i in result if i[0] in filter]
```

but I'm looking for a NumPy-type solution, like `np.where`. *And* this method returns a list of NumPy arrays, not an `ndarray`. So, completely unusable.

Do you know of such method?

#### Edit: sandbox for experimentation

Here's code to copy-paste if you'd like to try.

```
a = np.array([[0, 'asd'],[1, 'wat'],[2, 'cat'],[6, 'yep']])
b = np.array([1, 2], dtype=str)

out = np.array([i for i in a if i[0] in b])
> array([['1', 'wat'], ['2', 'cat']])
```

Comment: You forgot to give ```result``` in your example.

Comment: @Kefeng91 Oops, the array names are now fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you like to get such result?

```
>>> c = a[np.where(np.in1d(a[:, 0], b))]
>>> c
array([['1', 'wat'],
       ['2', 'cat']],
      dtype='<U11')
>>> type(c)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! I knew there was such a function.